# python install script import error

Tags: python, import, installation, package, anaconda

I am using the anaconda python distribution and am having an issue running the script. I am using the command, 'sudo python setup.py install' on the script. Below is the a  few lines of the install script (where the error seems to occur):

```
try:
    from nisext.sexts import package_check, get_comrec_build
except ImportError:
    raise RuntimeError('Need nisext package from nibabel installation'
                       ' - please install nibabel first')
```

when I run 'sudo python setup.py install', I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Need nisext package from nibabel installation'
RuntimeError: Need nisext package from nibabel installation - please install nibabel first
```

This does not make any sense to me, as I have the necessary package in the current environment. When I open python using the 'python' command and manually type the line 'from nisext.sexts import package_check,get_comrec_build', the package imports fine and a new line is presented by python (indicating to my knowledge that the imports were successful). Does anybody know why this might occur? I am at a loss for why this error is being raised.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Am posting reply instead of deleting because it may be helpful for people new to linux as myself. Apparently, the sudo command runs in the root's environment and does not retain the virtual environment (which was the location of the packages, in my case). Therefore, the packages did not exist where python was looking for them, since it was looking in the default package location and not the virtual environment's packages.

Comment: You don't need to use `sudo` with Anaconda anyway, as it by default installs with user permissions. Using sudo will just lead to future permissions issues because it will write files with permissions such that you need to use `sudo` again to modify or delete them.